# How to use Entity Framework Core data migrations to add seed data to existing seed data

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, core-data-migration, seeding

I've inherited a project that uses data migrations (.NET Core 3) to seed some data using the `EntityTypeBuilder.HasData()` method. The code already creates rows and the database already has these rows inserted.

I now want to add additional rows of data to the existing rows, so I've added these as parameters including the primary key. When the migration code executes, the new rows are included but nothing is added to the data.

Here's an example - builder is `EntityTypeBuilder<entityName>`

```
builder.HasData(new entityName { Id = 1, name = "Fred" }, 
                new entityName { Id = 2, name = "Sam" });
```

These already exist in the database.

I now want to add 2 more rows to the existing data

```
builder.HasData(new entityName { Id = 1, name = "Fred" }, 
                new entityName { Id = 2, name = "sam" }, 
                new entityName { Id = 3, name = "john" }, 
                new entityName { Id = 4, name = "andrew" });
```

The code runs with no errors, but the data in the table still only has the original 2 rows.

This is just an example, the actual seed data has over 100 rows, I want to add a further 40. Are there any other steps I need to take to force the additional data to be added ?

Answer (score 2):

Have you created a new migration after editing the seed data?

E.g.

```
PM> Add-Migration SeedNewData
```

Applying it:

```
PM> Update-Database
```

See [Use Code First Migrations to Seed the Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-3)

Answer (score 0):

If this is something you going to use a lot, i recommend you use the concept of seed on initialization, just need to call a method that seed data in your database. Here is an example:

The static Seed class, that going to insert, update, delete in your contex:

```
public static class Seed
{
        public static void SeedData(this IApplicationBuilder applicationBuilder, EfContext context, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            // (First time) Check a new version and call the method for your version
            if (!context.SystemConfiguration.Any() || context.SystemConfiguration.FirstOrDefault().DatabaseVersion == 0)
            {
                V1(context, serviceProvider);
            }
         
            // For the second, you just need to increment the the database version and so on...
            if (context.SystemConfiguration.Last().DatabaseVersion == 1)
            {
                V2(context, serviceProvider);
            }
        }

        private static void V1(EfContext context, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            InsertOnTableA(context);            
            InsertOnTableB(context);
            DropTableC(context);
            UpdateSomethingOnTableD(context);

            // Update the version of the databasen and save changes           
            var config = new SystemConfiguration(databaseVersion: 1);
            context.SystemConfiguration.Add(config);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        private static void V2(EfContext context, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            // Do something..

            // Update the version of the databasen and save changes           
            var config = new SystemConfiguration(databaseVersion: 2);
            context.SystemConfiguration.Add(config);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
}
```

And you just have to call it in your app initialization (Configure on Startup.cs) like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, EfContext context)
{            
    // Seed the database
    app.SeedData(context, serviceProvider);
    
    // your other stuff goes here ...
}
```

As with this, you will need an entity to store the database version for you to keep track on your database version (in this case "SystemConfiguration"), so you can do a lot, like insert data using other data as parameter, update, delete and so on without depending on migrations